# Phpstorm, generate getters & setters

Tags: php, phpstorm

Подскажите, почему phpstorm может не создать геттеры и сеттеры? Вот код:

```
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Variables
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $code;
    private $value;
    private $id_language;
}
```

Жму `alt+ins`, в появившемся меняю выбрал поля, для которых мне нужны и те и другие, жму `ок` и ничего не происходит, ошибок тоже нет. В чем проблема? Так же, когда начинаю писать ручками, например : `public function`, интеллект мне высвечивает что бы сразу создать готовый, но при нажатии на него снова ничего не происходит(на скриншоте пример), в чем моя ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте через пкм-> generate -> getters and setters

Comment: @AntonKucenko тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Помогла переустановка. Так же перестал генерить класс во время создания нового.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Insert (⌘ N), выбрать пункт меню "Getter and Setter"

[Инструкция](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/generating-code.html#generate-getters-setters) от JetBrains по генерации геттеров и сеттеров в PhpStorm

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)